# Core data, populating my Coredata with my jSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, core-data

where is my probleme ? i want to populate my coredata with my json but its only populate the last object, i mean this one :

```
phone.name = [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"name"];
        phone.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
```

and not the previous ones.

this is my code :

```
- (void) add{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    Phone *phone = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Phone" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if (nameText.text.length <= 0 || numberText.text.length <= 0)
    {
        NSLog(@" hey hey, t'as pas oublié kkchose ?");
    }
    else
    {
        phone.name = nameText.text;
        phone.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[ numberText.text intValue]];

        NSLog(@"ADD : %@", phone.name);

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test" object:self];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/json.txt"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]; 
    NSError *err;

    NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray* )[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];


   for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
    {
        phone.name = [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
        phone.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
  }


    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Phone" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *array  = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

    for (Phone *pho in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"NAME %@", pho.name);
        NSLog(@"PHONE %@", pho.number);
    }

}
```

btw, if you have an idea to make me not coding a loop to populate the core data, i will thanks you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create one Managed Object in this line:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
```

And then you set the name and number fields three times in these lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
{
    phone.name = [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
    phone.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
}
```

I guess you want to create and populate three objects instead of just one. Move the creation of the managed object inside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
{
    Phone *phone = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Phone" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    phone.name = [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
    phone.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
}
```